# How to quickly open a JS file linked by web form's ScriptReference in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, navigation

is there a way (preferably a KB shortcut) to quickly open in Visual Studio source editor a JavaScript file linked via a ScriptReference in a web-form (.aspx) file? Consider the code snippet below:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>   
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Common/js/controls/search-client.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

What I want is to be able to place caret on the Path's attribute value, hit a KB shortcut and have the search-client.js file opened in a new VS tab, just as F12 works for codebehind. Thanks.